# WatchOS 2: ExternalAccessory/ExternalAccessory.h

Tags: ios9, watchos-2

Does the ExternalAccessory framework exist for WatchOS 2? I managed to create a WatchKit project that uses it and all is good.

However moving to OS2, CFNetwork and other frameworks are missing.  I can't select it when picking frameworks (Linked), if I link (Embedded Binary) to it, my code can not see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only framework available for Watch are listed here:

Extensions built specifically for watchOS 2 have access to the following system frameworks:

- ClockKit Framework
- Contacts Framework
- Core Data Framework
- Core Foundation Framework
- Core Graphics Framework
- Core Location Framework
- Core Motion Framework
- EventKit Framework
- Foundation Framework
- HealthKit Framework
- HomeKit Framework
- Image I/O
- Collection MapKit Framework
- Mobile Core Services Framework
- PassKit Framework
- Security Framework
- Watch Connectivity Framework
- WatchKit Framework Reference

You can find all the information about avaiable framework on this Apple Site
https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleWatch2TransitionGuide/LeverageSystemTechnologies.html